# Cassandra Clustering Failure handling

Tags: cassandra

How Cassandra behaves when the contact node is dead? I mean to say, Cassandra has the ring structure of "n" nodes, If client is going to access that first node but it is dead. The first node is specified in the java client.
I could not understand the failure handling. Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the client, different client do different things to deal with this, but with most drivers you can supply several contact points.

**Astyanax** uses token discovery to keep track of various nodes in the cluster. [*Full docs here*](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Configuration).

> The host supplier associates the connection pool with a dynamic host registry. The connection pool will frequently poll this supplier for the current list of hosts and update its internal host connection pools to account for new or removed hosts.

This is configured during when you are setting up your context:

```
AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    ...
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
        .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.TOKEN_AWARE)
    )
...
context.start();
```

The DataStax java driver handles failure well as long as you've supplied multiple contact points. If you have 3 nodes with a SimpleStrategy for replication and replication factor of 3 (aka all data is present on all 3 nodes) than you can query as long as one of the 3 nodes is alive.

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                         .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                         .addContactPoint("127.0.0.2")
                         .addContactPoint("127.0.0.3")
                         .build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks , So, If we are using clustering obviously we should use connection pool to manage failures. Am I wright ?

Comment: @user2560319 I still dont know what client you are using, and Astyanax and the DataStax driver handle connection pooling for you anyway! Hector is an outdated driver so I would avoid it. DataStax's driver would be best for handling failures and I would recommend it unless you need to use the Thrift protocol.

Comment: Oops, I am using Hector Client. For example If you are going to created a could based system which driver is best for handling failures and has support functionality?

Comment: Check my previous comment... DataStax's driver gets daily updates and you can find the driver's developer in the #cassandra chatroom on the freenode IRC network.

Comment: It sounds great. Thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one node, or only specify one node, and that node is down then the client won't be able to connect (obviously); but usually a client library, like Hector, will allow you to specify a group of nodes and maintain a connection pool, connecting to which ever node is available.

The Hector [documentation](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/wiki/User-Guide#basic-configuration-and-setup) goes in to a little more detail, but the simplest way to specify multiple nodes is by passing a comma-separated list of hosts in the `CassandraHostConfigurator` when creating a cluster:

```java
String hosts = "node1.example.com:9160, node2.example.com:9160, node3.example.com:9160";
Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(CLUSTER_NAME, new CassandraHostConfigurator(hosts));
```

Comment: Can I able to create connection pool using Hector Client ? Is there any tutorials to give info about connection pool using Hector ?